# Measure that dynamically calculates average cost (avoiding circular dependency)

Tags: powerbi, dax, circular-dependency

I imported an Excel table with thousands of purchases and sales transactions of shares of stock.

The imported data: traded **tickers**, transaction **dates**, number of traded **shares**, **types of trade** (purchase or sale), and traded **share prices**.

I then calculated a measure that manages to tally the running **Shares balance** after each purchase/sale transaction occurs under each row of data.

3 other measures are also easily calculated:

- **Purchase total:** Traded (purchased) shares x Share price
- **Total revenue:** Traded (sold) shares x Share price
- **Total cost:** Traded (sold) shares x Average cost

I then need to calculate the last measure being **Average cost**, and that's where I get stuck with a **circular dependency issue**...

The rationale behind this calculation is as follows:

- **If the transaction is a sale**, just pick up the **prior Average cost** from the same column.
- But **if the transaction is a purchase**, then [**ALL Purchase totals up to the respective date** *for the respective ticker* + **ALL Total cost (negative) BEFORE the respective date** *for the respective ticker*] **DIVIDED BY the shares balance at the respective date**.

The below screenshot tries to illustrate everything described above (I hope it doesn't end up providing a confusing picture...):

[image]

Since the actual code is pretty lengthy I'll split it up into 4 sections to make it easier to comprehend.

**1)** The **prior Average cost** picked up from the same column is computed by the following code:

```
Average cost = 
VAR Avg_Cost_Tbl = 
    CALCULATETABLE( 
        ADDCOLUMNS( 
            SUMMARIZE( 
                fTrans, 
                fTrans[Ticker], 
                fTrans[Date] 
            ), 
            "@AvgCost", [Average cost]
        ), 
        fTrans[Ticker] = fTrans[Ticker], 
        fTrans[Date] <= fTrans[Date] 
    )
VAR Prior_Avg_Cost = 
    FILTER( 
        Avg_Cost_Tbl, 
        SELECTCOLUMNS( 
            OFFSET( 
                -1, 
                Avg_Cost_Tbl, 
                ORDERBY( fTrans[Ticker], ASC, fTrans[Date], ASC ) 
            ), 
            [@AvgCost] 
        )
    )
```

**2)** **ALL Purchase totals up to the respective date** *for the respective ticker* is calculated by the following code:

```
VAR Purch_Total_Tbl =
    CALCULATETABLE( 
        ADDCOLUMNS( 
            SUMMARIZE( 
                fTrans, 
                fTrans[Ticker], 
                fTrans[Date], 
                fTrans[Transaction] 
            ), 
            "@PurchTotal", [Purchase total]
        ), 
        fTrans[Ticker] = fTrans[Ticker], 
        fTrans[Date] <= fTrans[Date], 
        fTrans[Transaction] = "Purchase"
    )
VAR Purch_Total_Sum = 
    IF( 
        HASONEVALUE( fTrans[Ticker] ), 
        SUMX( 
            WINDOW( 
                1, 
                ABS, 
                0, 
                REL, 
                Purch_Total_Tbl, 
                ORDERBY( fTrans[Date], ASC ), 
                , 
                PARTITIONBY( fTrans[Ticker] ) 
            ), 
            [@PurchTotal] 
        ) 
    )
```

**3)** **ALL Total cost PRIOR to the respective date** *for the respective ticker* is calculated by the following code:

```
VAR Total_Cost_Tbl =
    CALCULATETABLE( 
        ADDCOLUMNS( 
            SUMMARIZE( 
                fTrans, 
                fTrans[Ticker], 
                fTrans[Date], 
                fTrans[Transaction] 
            ), 
            "@Total_Cost", [Total cost]
        ), 
        fTrans[Ticker] = fTrans[Ticker], 
        fTrans[Date] <= fTrans[Date], 
        fTrans[Transaction] = "Sale"
    )
VAR Total_Cost_Sum = 
    IF( 
        HASONEVALUE( fTrans[Ticker] ), 
        SUMX( 
            WINDOW( 
                1, 
                ABS, 
                -1, 
                REL, 
                Total_Cost_Tbl, 
                ORDERBY( fTrans[Date], ASC ), 
                , 
                PARTITIONBY( fTrans[Ticker] ) 
            ), 
            [@Total_Cost] 
        ) 
    )
```

**4)** Finally, the above 3 pieces of code come together via the following code:

```
RETURN
    SUMX( 
        fTrans, 
        IF( 
            fTrans[Transaction] = "Sale", 
            Purch_Total_Sum, 
            DIVIDE( 
                Purch_Total_Sum + Total_Cost_Sum, 
                [Saldo de cotas] 
            ) 
        ) 
    )
```

But then I keep getting the **circular dependency error message**, which **I tried to avoid by making sure the code picks up dependent data from PRIOR rows**, albeit I fail on attempting to do so.

How can I get this code fixed to achieve that? Or should a completely different calculation approach be taken?

I suppose calculated columns could be a way to achieve that but I'd like to avoid that route as we're talking about a table with tens of thousands of rows of data.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
VAR Total_Cost_Tbl =
    CALCULATETABLE( 
        ADDCOLUMNS( 
            SUMMARIZE( 
                fTrans, 
                fTrans[Ticker], 
                fTrans[Date], 
                fTrans[Transaction] 
            ), 
            "@Total_Cost", [Total cost]
        ), 
        fTrans[Ticker] = fTrans[Ticker], 
        fTrans[Date] <= fTrans[Date], 
        fTrans[Transaction] = "Sale"
    )
VAR Total_Cost_Sum = 
    IF( 
        HASONEVALUE( fTrans[Ticker] ), 
        SUMX( 
            WINDOW( 
                1, 
                ABS, 
                -1, 
                REL, 
                Total_Cost_Tbl, 
                ORDERBY( fTrans[Date], ASC ), 
                , 
                PARTITIONBY( fTrans[Ticker] ) 
            ), 
            [@Total_Cost] 
        ) 
    )
```

Comment: ???????????????